# Is $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{p_{p_k}}$, where $p_k$ is the $k$-th prime, irrational? transcendental?

Tags: sequences-and-series, irrational-numbers, transcendental-numbers

I was reading about the reason why the reciprocals of the primes have a divergent sum. So I was thinking of changing the index to the $k$th prime. We get: $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{p_{p_k}}=S$$ When I first posted this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4569929/does-this-function-have-triple-log-behavior), I was thinking that it was a divergent series like its predecessor. But @GregMartin pointed out that this sum actually converges. So I was wondering if this number is irrational? Could it also be transcendental? I am afraid this question is as hard as proving that Euler's constant $\gamma$ is transcendental.

Edit: I understand that this question is very hard to solve. So maybe is there any explanation why it might not be solvable by current methods?

Comment: what is the context of this problem?

Comment: @Mike added context :)

Comment: Special thanks to @Blue!

Comment: It is not even known whether $\gamma$ is irrational, and the sequence probably converges too slow to apply something like Roth's theorem.

Comment: I would say that $p_{p_k}$ is actually about $k\log^2 k$ so definitely much less than $2^k$ but convergent indeed

Comment: By standard inequalities $p_k \le 2k\log k$ for large enough $k$ so $p_{p_k} \le 5k\log^2 k$ for large $k$ so $1/p_{p_k} \ge 1/(5k \log^2k)$ for large $k$ so it is definitely not less than $1/2^k$; what happens for a few terms is irrelevant

Comment: @KamalSaleh Apparently fixed, I was not confused about the claimed convergence , but about $S<1$ and the comparison test with the now deleted geometric sum.

Comment: @Peter turns out that $S>1$, I compared $1/2^x$ with $1/x(\log x)^2$ on Desmos.

Comment: It would be *extremely* surprising/amazing to me if it turned out to be algebraic. Most likely it is transcendental, but the proof of this is far out of our reach. As for why - well, the distribution of primes in general seems to be pseudo-random, and the best we can usually hope for is some inequalities or asymptotics.  These methods will not tell you anything about whether it's transcendental or irrational. But who knows? If a proof existed it would be quite wonderful.

Comment: @JairTaylor Heard of Willan's formula? Your comment could've been an answer, you know :)

Comment: No, but that it is a wonderful formula.  I'll let someone else answer who is more knowledgeable in this area. Cheers

Comment: @JairTaylor Cheers! But I wonder how the primes would be pseudo random if there is a formula already. In every book or every time I here about advanced number theory, they say that the Riemann hypothesis could give the best approximation of the prime number distribution, although Willans made an implicit formula for it.

Comment: The pseudo-randomness is only a heuristic - of course, the primes are deterministic.  Nonetheless, it can be illuminating to model them as randomly distributed. See e.g. [this](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2015/01/04/254a-supplement-4-probabilistic-models-and-heuristics-for-the-primes-optional/) post by Terry Tao. Just because there's a formula doesn't mean it can't be pseudo-random in this sense.