# Creating Bounds for $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{p_{p_k}}$ where $p_k$ is the $k$th prime

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, prime-numbers, upper-lower-bounds

In another [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4575253/is-sum-k-1-infty-frac1p-p-k-where-p-k-is-the-k-th-prime-irrat) I asked if $S=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{p_{p_k}}$ (where $p_k$ is the $k$th prime) is irrational, transcendental, or both. I thought that this number was less than $1$ by comparing it to $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k}$ but it turns out that $1/p_{p_k}\sim1/k(\log k)^2$ is greater than $1/2^k$ and the first few terms don't help in creating an upper bound. However I now know that $S>1$ which creates a lower bound. How could I bound $S$ from above? I have a feeling it is less than $2$.

Comment: The sum diverges, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_of_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes

Comment: @fourofour_un This is $1/p_k$ and not $1/p_{p_k}$

Comment: Why should this one converge?  $p_k\sim k\log k\implies p_{p_k}\sim p_{k\log k}\sim k\log k \log (k\log k)$  and that sum surely diverges.

Comment: @lulu https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4569929/does-this-function-have-triple-log-behavior

Comment: Computing the exact sum up to $k=10^5$  and curve fitting as in my answer predicts an asymptotic value of $1.0344$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Rosser's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosser%27s_theorem) and theories about bounding primes that are related. It is known that $$n\ln n<p_n$$ for $n\ge 1$ so from that (due to monotonicity of the mapping $[x\mapsto\ln x]$) follows $$n\ln n \ln (n\ln n)\le p_n\ln p_n\le p_{p_n}.$$ Therefore  $$\sum\frac{1}{p_{p_n}}\le \sum\frac{1}{n\ln n \ln (n\ln n)}$$ at least after some *$n$-time* like for $n\ge 3$. Sorry for being laconic but I have no time now yet I wanted give some hints how to obtain precise upper bound. Later on we have $$\sum_{n\ge 3}\frac{1}{p_{p_n}}\le \sum_{n\ge 3}\frac{1}{n\ln n \ln (n\ln n)}\le \sum_{n\ge 3}\frac{1}{n\ln^2n }\le \frac{1}{3\ln^2 3}+\int_{3}^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x\ln^2 x}=\frac{1}{3\ln^2 3}+\frac{1}{\ln 3}.$$

See also [Integral test for convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence) for the last inequality.

Really fun fact that i discovered. **Wolfram Alpha** neither **Mathematica 12** can not properly evaluated the series $$\sum_{n\ge 3}\frac{1}{n\ln n \ln (n\ln n)}.$$
You can see it here: [$\sum_{n\ge 3}\frac{1}{n\ln n \ln (n\ln n)}$ by Wolfram.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum%20from%20n%3D3%20to%20infty%20of%201%2F%28n*ln%20n*%20ln%28n*ln%20n%29%29)

Comment: [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/) also fails to compute the last sum out-of-the-box. But, with
$$\small\begin{aligned}
&\texttt{foo(z)=1/(z*log(z)*log(z*log(z)));}\\
&\texttt{realpart(a)=intnum(x=log(log(a)),[oo,1],1/(x+exp(x)));}\\
&\texttt{cplxpart(a)=2*intnum(x=0,[oo,2*Pi],imag(foo(a+I*x))/(exp(2*Pi*x)+1));}\\
&\texttt{goo(a)=realpart(a)+cplxpart(a);}
\end{aligned}$$
(a tweak of the Abel-Plana approach), `goo(5/2)` produces $$\small\sum_{n=3}^\infty\frac1{n\log n\log(n\log n)}\approx0.87072989422834088558173074566226429537879131941283183669\dots$$

Comment: I tried evaluating $S$ using wolfram before asking the question and it returned "diverges" lol.

Comment: Well maybe I shouldn't say that "there is a problem with evaluating" since you can always brute force it. Rather there's a problem with deciding about convergence of the series. Just Wolfram and Mathematica did it wrong (and now we know PARI/GP as well). You can ask Mathematica $\texttt{SumConvergence[f,n]}$ and the answer is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

*Too long for a comment*

Starting from @Marek Kryspin's answer and using `Mathematica (version 13.1)`

$$S_p=\sum_{n=3}^{10^p}\frac{1}{n \log (n) \log (n \log (n))}$$ gives
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
p & S_p \\
 1 & 0.538719 \\
 2 & 0.691952 \\
 3 & 0.747124 \\
 4 & 0.775812 \\
 5 & 0.793509 \\
 6 & 0.805559 \\
\cdots & \cdots \\
\infty & 0.870730 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Using the values for $1\leq p\leq 6$ a quick and dirty regression
$$S_p=\frac {a+b\,p}{1+c\,p}$$ gives a quite good fit
$$\begin{array}{l|lll}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Std Error} &
   \text{Confidence Interval} \\
\hline
 a & -1.80803 & 0.08595 & \{-2.08156,-1.53449\} \\
 b & +6.20879 & 0.23007 & \{+5.47661,+6.94098\} \\
 c & +7.16857 & 0.26878 & \{+6.31319,+8.02394\} \\
\end{array}$$ and then an asymptotic value of $0.866114$ which does not look totally stupid.
The residuals are
$$\{-0.000025,0.000196,-0.000169,-0.000185,-0.000022,0.000206\}$$

Concerning
$$\int_{3}^\infty \frac{dn}{n \log (n) \log (n \log (n))}=0.720329$$

Comment: A lot of effort, it is hard to decide if @MarekKryspin or your answer is the best one. The last integral is the result, right?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain, but what about simple bound:
$p_n \approx n \log n \Rightarrow p_{p_n} \approx p_{n \log n} \approx n \log n \log (n \log n)$.

Hence we have:
$$
\sum_{k} \frac{1}{p_{p_k}} \approx \int_A^{\infty} \dfrac{dx}{x \log x \log (x \log x)}
$$

Comment: It's that simple? Wow. So what's $A$?

Comment: @KamalSaleh some constant (we need $x \log x > 0$).

Comment: does $x=1$ work, or does it not include $0$?

Comment: @KamalSaleh. With $A=2$, the integral is $1.42474$